# Perl. shared hash threads in 2 files

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, shared

please help me resolve my problems with shared hash threads in 2 files

my first file "H.pl" contain defined hash (very huge with many levels):

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
our %h;
%h= (
        "hd",
                {
                    "0",    {"type",    "fix",  "ln",   "8",    "descr",    "P"},
                    "1",    {"type",    "hex",  "ln",   "2",    "descr",    "H"},
                },
        "hdr",
                {
                    "0",    {"type",    "fix",  "ln",   "8",    "descr",    "E"},
                },
    );
```

second file "V.pl" contain main code and threads for change hash:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;
use lib '.';

require 'H.pl';

our %h;
threads->create(sub{  
                    
                    print "befor change in threads \n";
                    print Dumper \%h;  
                    
                    $h{"hd"}{"0"}{"value"}  = "hello"; 
                    $h{"hd"}{"0"}{"descr"}  = "R"; 
                    $h{"hdr"}{"0"}{"value"}  = "hello"; 
                    
                    print "after change in threads  \n";
                    print Dumper \%h;  
                    
                    }
                );

sleep 1;

print "without threads  \n";
print Dumper \%h;
```

I tried use `our %h:shared;` in both files, but always get error `Invalid value for shared scalar at H.pl`
How I can share my hash?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> Shared variables can only store scalars, refs of shared variables, or
> refs of shared data (discussed in next section):

If you want to share a hash that's not shallow, you need to share the inner references first.

You can use the `shared_clone` function for that. Adding the following line into V.pl below `our %h` makes the programs work:

```
%h = %{ shared_clone(\%h) };
```

Also, store the result of `create` to a variable `$t` and instead of `sleep`, run `$t->join`.

It's usually better to use a higher level module like [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue) and only send the data you actually need between threads.

Comment: I need to share whole hash

Comment: Then you need to share all the inner structures. In the end, the resulting code might be much slower than without threads. Are you sure you need threads for this?

Comment: even when i added all structures of hash - i get error. because i have 2 files. when i combine to 1 file and add next code `our %h:shared;

$h{"hd"} = &share( {} );
$h{"hd"}{"0"} = &share( {} );
$h{"hd"}{"0"}{"value"} = &share( {} );` its works, but with 2 files doesn`t works

Comment: How did you add them? Did you add the inner structures recursively? Show code, please.

Comment: <pre> #require 'H.pl';
our %h:shared;
$h{"hd"} = &share( {} );
$h{"hd"}{"0"} = &share( {} );
$h{"hd"}{"0"}{"value"} = &share( {} );
threads->create(sub{  
     
     print "befor change in threads \n";
     print Dumper \%h;  
     
     $h{"hd"}{"0"}{"value"}  = "hello"; 
     #$h{"hd"}{"0"}{"descr"}  = "R"; 
     #$h{"hdr"}{"0"}{"value"}  = "hello"; 
     
     print "after change in threads  \n";
     print Dumper \%h;  
     
     }
    );

sleep 1;

print "without threads  \n";
print Dumper \%h;   <code>

Comment: Try `%h = %{ shared_clone(\%h) }` instead.

Comment: `Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at`